# Codeigniter GD Library Image Resize Not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, gd, image-resizing

I tried to resizeing images using codeignater GD library.It's works fine on my local machine.

```
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = 'test_img/img_1.jpg';  //local path
    echo $config['source_image'];
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 500;
    $config['height'] = 500;
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
```

But we actually store images in Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3).So I changed the path to the S3 bucket.And permissions are given.

$config['source_image'] =  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/folder_name/53.jpg';

Then i got an error,
"The path to the image is not correct.
Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.."

I tried to do this thing in different ways but I coudn't achieve this.Need your help.

Regards,
Kosala

Comment: Please check gd enabled on your server or not.

Answer (score 3):

you have to use relative path

```
$config['source_image'] = './folder_name/53.jpg';
```